# how to access Assets in android?

Tags: android

edit: fixed it with

```
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(getAssets().open("totalkeys.zip"));
```

---

I got an unzipper ( decompress ) from an example, where it takes a string as a path to a zipped file. But since I have the file in my assets, I somehow need to make to read it from there... well, got this far.

Unfortunately it throws me "ERROR/Decompress(24122): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream" Any ideas how to fix it? )

```
public class dec extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(this, "hello, starting to unZipp!", 15500).show();

        String location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipped/"; 
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        try  { 

            AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();

            FileInputStream fin = (FileInputStream)mgr.open("totalkeys.zip");
            // throws ERROR/Decompress(24122): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream

            //FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); /// old one, that wanted a String.
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
            ZipEntry ze = null; 
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
              Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

              if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
                dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
              } else { 
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName()); 
                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
                  fout.write(c); 
                } 

                zin.closeEntry(); 
                fout.close(); 
              } 

            } 
            zin.close(); 
          } catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
          } 

        } 

        private void dirChecker(String dir) { 

          String location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipped/"; 
          File f = new File(location + dir); 

          if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
            f.mkdirs(); 
          } 

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        finish();

}

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use your context:

```
InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open("totalkeys.zip");
```

This returns an input stream which you can read to a buffer.

```
// Open the input stream
InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0){
          // write buffer some where, e.g. to an output stream
          // as 'myOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);'
}
// Close the stream
try{
    is.close();
} catch(IOException e){
    Log.e(this.getLocalClassName().toString(), e.getMessage());
    //this.getLocalClassName().toString() could be replaced with any (string) tag
}
```

If you're working in an activity, you can use `this.getAssets()` because `Activity` extends `Context`. You can also pass an instance of `Context` to a custom constructor if you're not working inside an activity and assign this to a member if you need it later.

Comment: thanks! just one more thing, how do I get the Context if I'm not in an activity, but simply in a class. see edited above.

Comment: If you're instantiating inside an `Activity`, create a custom constructor for your class which takes as an argument a `Context` where you can pass `this` from your activity. You can set this to a member of type `Context`. If you can also pass the context along a chain of constructors, or setters, if need be. If you're really not creating from an activity or you don't have a `Context` to hand, you're probably doing some thing bad but you can try calling `getApplicationContext()`; the doc is here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext()

Comment: I made it simpler, by putting the unzipper into it own activity, which gets called from a service. See edit above. Right now the only problem is that it throws "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream".

Comment: Instead of getting the base context, why not take the context the activity can access? i.e. you can now try `InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("totalkeys.zip");` instead. You'll need to treat a possible IOException here.

Comment: Fixed it by "ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(getAssets().open("totalkeys.zip")); "